# Load complete object after refresh with Spring Data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm having a problem loading all the properties of my object after running the update. My project is using Spring boot and Spring data.
My class is configured like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Cliente {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "cadastro", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDate cadastro;
    private String nome;
    private String ramoDeAtuacao;

    // get() e set()
}
```

My repositrory:

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente, Long> {
}
```

Note that the registration date will only be generated once when I create a new Cliente using the **Save method.** This operation occurs in my Service:

```
@Service
public class ClienteServiceImpl implements ClienteService {
    private ClienteRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ClienteServiceImpl(ClienteRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }


    @Override
    public Cliente save(Cliente cliente) {
        cliente.setCadastro(LocalDate.now());
        return repository.save(cliente);
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente update(Cliente cliente) {
        return repository.save(cliente);
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/clientes")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService service;

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> atualiza(@RequestBody Cliente cliente) {
        Cliente clienteAtualizado = service.atualiza(cliente);
        return new ResponseEntity<Cliente>(clienteAtualizado, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is the JSON sent to create a new Client.

```
{
    "nome": "Thiago",
    "ramoDeAtuacao": "T.I."
}
```

The returned JSON has the registration date is this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "cadastro": "20/07/2019",
    "nome": "Thiago",
    "ramoDeAtuacao": "T.I."
}
```

Now, when I try to upgrade, I can not return the registration date. Here is the update JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Thiago MF",
    "ramoDeAtuacao": "Desenvolvedor"
}
```

The returned JSON does not have the registration date and returns NULL:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "cadastro": null,
    "nome": "Thiago MF",
    "ramoDeAtuacao": "Desenvolvedor"
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using Spring Data Rest auto generated endpoint? If not, add your controller code. Also how are you updating. If using SDR then send a PATCH request as youi are not including all fields.

Comment: Hello Alan Hay, thanks for the message. I added my controller class code and I am currently using @PostMapping. I'll check the use of Path. As for the problem, it does not occur anymore. I followed Vishnu's suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query does not have the date field, so existing field in the database gets updated with null.

If you need to update only the fields other than the date field then update function should be something like

```
@Override
public Cliente update(Cliente cliente) {

    Cliente c = repository.findOne(id);
    // Now set the values to be updated on c from cliente
    return repository.save(c);
}
```

Comment: No need for repository.save() if the service is transactional (as it should be)

Comment: Hello Vishnu. I followed the suggestion and it worked. Thank you.